# What does the JVM in MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR) do?

Tags: java, matlab

I would like to find out what is the purpose of the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) in the MCR and what is the effect if I invoke the `-NOJVM` flag in `MWApplication.initializeApplication()`?

As I have written an Java application which contain an GUI, and I tried with/without `-NOJVM` option. And only the `LookandFeel` of the GUI change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matlab contains an internal JVM, which is used for all Matlab-generated GUI (figures, dialog windows, the desktop/editor etc.). By starting Matlab with the -NOJVM switch, you're basically using Matlab as a pure computational engine (the engine is c/c++-based and does not use the JVM). If all your GUI is handled externally to Matlab, then perhaps you don't need the internal JVM, which carries a memory and startup-performance cost.

Comment: What if you want to enable your MCR standalone application to use an external JVM? (same effect as setting the MATLAB_JAVA environment variable on a machine with MATLAB). Is that possible?

Answer (score -3):

I am just guessing since I really don't know Matlab, but maybe its just a flag to Matlab to instruct him to use its internal JVM or use the operating system JVM.

For example in the Matlab directory under "C:\windows\program files" you may find a directory containing the JRE of Java and this is the one used by default, however if you use the -NOJVM flag it will ignore its internal JRE and go find the default JRE of the system which is usually the which the environment variable JAVA_HOME points to.

Its just a guess and nothing else ;-)